# Cakephp aggregation query (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, aggregation-framework

Using [ichikaway-cakephp](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb) I am trying to convert following query (running fine in php) to cakephp

In cakephp it returns empty array

**Core PHP**

```
  $out = $collection->aggregate(array(
     array('$unwind' => '$as'),
     array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array('as'=>'$as'),
           'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
        )
    )
));
```

**Cakephp**

```
$conditions=array('aggregate'=>array(
                            array('$unwind' => '$as'),
                            array(
                                '$group' => array(
                                    '_id' => array('as'=>'$as'),
                                   'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
                                )
                            )
                            ));

$results = $this->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

---

### ***I am unable to find aggrgation framework function in [test cases](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.2/Test/Case/Datasource/MongodbSourceTest.php)***

So far [only this](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/commit/0303bac2a652062d26c804cb06e4107fd24a1595) commit talks about aggregation.

Comment: Does it work if you change '_id' => array('as'=>'$as') to be '_id'=>'$as' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array(
    array('$unwind' => '$as'),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array('as'=>'$as'),
                'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
             )
        )
));

$mongo = $this->Post->getDataSource();
$mongoCollectionObject = $mongo->getMongoCollection($this->Post);


$results = $mongoCollectionObject->aggregate($params);
```